# Blender python non-english (Japanese) character in script

Tags: python, scripting, export, file-format

In blender 3.4+

When an object is named in Japanese,

and is used as export path with its own name,

the path becames unusable and returns error.

```
active_obj = bpy.context.active_object


# Export the stl file
path=os.path.join(filepath, "{}.{}".format(active_obj.name, "stl"))
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=path, use_selection = True)
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\mypath\\stl\\?胯?喋??1t)[1/32].RATIO.stl'
```

[image]

If object is in english, no error occurs.

Some older threads suggested to enable international fonts in user preferences might work but it couldnt't be found in Blender 3.4+

The script wont work with japanese characters even when switched to japanese interface in blender.

Is there a clean way to have the script supports all langauge?

Comment: As a simple workaround, you might consider replacing a `word` written in Kanji/Kana with `hash(word)` whenever you name or open a file

Comment: I don't think it's because of the Japanese, it's because of the / in the path. It interprets that as a file named `32].RATIO.stl` in a folder named `クリンガー(1t)[1`. Since the folder doesn't exist, it errors. Try it without the slash in the name.

Comment: @scurest oh yes u are right! silly me, can u put this into an answer or what so i can accept it?